# How to check a jointJS element not based on type but on stencil name instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, jointjs, rappid

I want in Rappid to **make a check when inserting an element inside Paper**, if this element is Workitem or Activity but the only similar check I found in Rappid documentation is:

`if (cell.get('type') !== 'link'){//Do something}`

which checks if  this element is a link or not. Is there any way to check not based on `'type'` but based on `'name'` instead(where 'name is one of the Stencil names of basic shapes)?

I mean how will I check if an element is a shape with Stencil name Activity or Workitem?

And where please can I perform this check inside my code since I try so far in the creation of my `halo` to insert a single line of code and I can't.(e.x. I can't even do this `cell.set('wi_name', "ACTIVITY");` to set an inspector field with name wi_name having the name Activity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem this way:

```
if (cell.get('type') === 'basic.Rect'){}
```

Where `basic.Rect` is the basic shape with name either `Activity` or `Workitem` as stated in the Stencil.

Answer (score 1):

The type can also be retrieved directly through object *attributes*:

```
if (cell.attributes.type === 'basic.Rect'){}
```

Notice that if you are looking into an `ElementView` object (e.g. using `this` in events when [extending ElementView to create constraints](https://resources.jointjs.com/tutorial/constraint-move-to-circle)), you need to access the `model`:

```
if (elem.model.attributes.type === 'basic.Rect'){}
```

Or:

```
if (elem.model.get('type') === 'basic.Rect'){}
```